# Query failing to get MySQL data, not mysql_error() displaying

Tags: php, mysql

I am using phpmyadmin and had mySQL database working with my php until I started adding foreign key constraints. Then all of the sudden it stopped working. Now I'm backtracking to the very beginning when I ran my first query, but it still will not work (even though it used to). When I call for the mysql_error() nothing appears.

It seems so simple but I do not know what is going wrong. I even deleted out all of the tables from my database except the subjects table.

manage_content page (which should read my table):

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/header-home.php");?>


<?php
    // 2. Perform database query
    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($result);
?>


<div id="main">
  <div id="navigation">
        <ul class="subjects">
        <?php
            // 3. Use returned data (if any)
            while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                // output data from each row
        ?>
                <li><?php echo $subject["first_name"] . " (" . $subject["id"] . ")"; ?></li>
      <?php
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <h2>Manage Content</h2>

  </div>
</div>
<?php
  // 4. Release returned data
  mysqli_free_result($result);
?>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/footer.php");?>
```

Functions page:

```
<?php

    function confirm_query($result_set) {
        if (!$result_set) {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }

?>
```

Please help! I'm new and I know this is incredibly simple. I just don't know what I'm missing!

Comment: Have you tried to run `$query` in PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: try debugging by var_dump-ing the various variables you're using, starting with $connection

Comment: Yep query works in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do query you call `mysqlI_query()` function, but when you wanna get error, you do it with `mysql_query()`, try to change that!!

[mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: All I get now is: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in on line 7
Database query failed:

Comment: mysqli_query() need to be called with $mysqli connection object! see manual!

Comment: I'm sorry Michael, could you give me an example of how I would do that? I'm sorry I'm so new! I have a db_connection file I'm including at the beginning of each of these.

Comment: When you are making connection to database trough mysqli you make it something like

`$link = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);`

and you should pass that $link variable to mysqli_error();

Comment: So I should put $connection and in this function?
 function confirm_query($result_set) {
  if (!$result_set) {
   die("Database query failed." . mysqli_error());
  }
 }

Comment: `die("Database query failed." . mysqli_error($connection));` Like this!

Comment: Sigh. This is what I get when I do that: Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/bevinjohnston/sammies.dreamhosters.com/includes/functions.php on line 17
Database query failed.

Comment: I connect at the top of the manage_content page up in my post. Here is that page: <?php
define ("DB_SERVER", "xxx");
define ("DB_USER", "xxx");
define ("DB_PASS", "xxx");
define ("DB_NAME", "xxx");

  
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  // Test if connection succeeded
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . 
         mysqli_connect_error() . 
         " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
  }
?>

Comment: And when you var_dump that $connection, what does it show?

Comment: object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(75) "mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $" ["client_version"]=> int(50010) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(43) "mysql.servicetoamericamedals.org via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(10) "5.1.56-log" ["server_version"]=> int(50156) ["stat"]=> string(161) "Uptime:

Comment: 5938207 Threads: 9 Questions: 1125603206 Slow queries: 44081787 Opens: 14613519 Flush tables: 70 Open tables: 2048 Queries per second avg: 189.552" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(18601407) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }